# iPhone Whatsapp Lockscreen Notification Problem

Tags: iphone, notifications, lockscreen

Since upgrading Whatsapp to version 2.18.52 contact names do not appear on whatsapp lock screen notifications. For example, if I get a message from Mom, whatsapp only displays the whatsapp logo and “message”, without displaying the sender. I used to be able to see just the contact name (“Mom has sent you a message”), but now, no Names are displayed. This just happened as I updated to ios 11.3.1. Anyone having a similar problem? Please advise how I can fix this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem and got the below reply from whatsapp support

To turn on previews that display the contact name but not message:

Go to WhatsApp > Settings > Notifications > turn Show Preview on. Go to iPhone Settings > Notifications > WhatsApp > Show Previews > Never.